# "Он на этом собаку съел" — происхождение поговорки

Tags: фразеология

Фраза всем известна и означает, что человек — эксперт в каком-то вопросе, мастер своего дела. Но почему именно собаку? Откуда вообще взялась эта поговорка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Собаку съесть на чем, в чем - о том, кто является знатоком чего-либо, имеет богатый опыт в чем-либо. Есть несколько версий происхождения оборота.
1. Оборот появился в крестьянской среде, земледельческий труд тяжел: устанешь так, что с голоду и собаку бы съел.
2. У римских писателей встречается сходная поговорка: Linguam caninam comedit (букв. "язык собачий съел") - о том, кто разглагольствует без меры и без устали.
3. Фразеологизм восходит к свободному сочетанию слов, заключающему в себе насмешку над петрозаводцами, чуть не съевшими на свадьбе щи с собачатиной.
4. Выражение появилось в результате сокращения поговорки собаку съел, а хвостом подавился. Эта поговорка употребляется по отношению к человеку, который сделал что-то очень трудное и споткнулся на пустяке.

Answer (score 0):

Можно встретить толкование, согласно которому это выражение имеет древнейшие корни индийского происхождения, и связано оно с ритуальной в те времена игрой в кости (в Ригведе ей посвящен особый гимн). Поскольку «собакой» в этом действе назывался неудачный бросок игрока, то «убивший» (или «съевший») ее был, напротив, удачлив. «Махабхарата» описывает печальную историю одного царевича, который именно на «собаке» погорел, проиграв в кости и царство, и даже жену.

Источник: https://shkolazhizni.ru/culture/articles/21439/
© Shkolazhizni.ru